# Property does not exist on type But property exist

Tags: javascript, typescript

I can't understand why TypeScript throw out the error

```
interface SendMessageAction {
    type: 1;
}

interface DeleteMessageAction {
    type: 2;
    idBlock:string;
}

type ChatActionTypes = SendMessageAction | DeleteMessageAction;


const CounterReducer = (action:ChatActionTypes) => {
    action.idBlock
}
    Property 'idBlock' does not exist on type 'ChatActionTypes'.
    Property 'idBlock' does not exist on type 'SendMessageAction'.
```

Field idBlock exist in interface **DeleteMessageAction**

How to fix error?

Comment: It tells you exactly that it doesn't exist on `ChatActionTypes` nor on `SendMessageAction` yet, in your code you assume it does, cause you don't validate that the `action` is of type `DeleteMessageAction`, the only one that would have `idBlock`

Comment: Ok. I try figure out how work redux and typescript and in this example https://codesandbox.io/s/w02m7jm3q7 they use this construction https://prnt.sc/q1u8w5 without error. How?

Comment: if you would verify the `reducers.ts` in that same code page, you would see that they check which type the action is before doing something, so all you would need to do is verify that `action.type === 2` before you can do something with `action.idBlock`. Typescript should be intelligent enough to figure out that it is a `DeleteMessageAction` at that time

Comment: Cool, thx, now i understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you analyze the error message given, it says the following thing:

> Property 'idBlock' does not exist on type 'ChatActionTypes'.
>
> Property 'idBlock' does not exist on type 'SendMessageAction'.

[typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) cannot deduce from your usage that the `action: ChatActionTypes` is a `DeleteMessageAction`, as you have specified it as a `ChatActionTypes`. So Typescript warns you that it can't find it on 2 out of 3 possible matches for the `ChatActionTypes`.

If you would first validate the `type` on the `action` argument, [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) would be able to deduce that action is at that time a `DeleteMessageAction`, for example by doing:

```
const CounterReducer = (action:ChatActionTypes) => {
   if (action.type === 2) { // 2 is mentioned on DeleteMessageAction for type
     action.idBlock; // so you can now do something with idBlock here
   }
}
```